# PowerShell 4 SQL Server Insertions

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm using Powershell 4 and attempting to write data into a SQL Server 2012.

Here is the script I am using

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection↵
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=<SQLSERVER>;Initial Catalog=SYSINFO;Integrated Security=true;"
$conn.open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
```

The error I am getting is:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection] : verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

I assuemd the first line (Add-Type) would load all the required assemblies under System.Data

Am I missing somethign obvious?

Comment: Can you use -PassThru and see if the SQLConnection type is actually added ? Something like, Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Data" -PassThru | ForEach-Object { if($_.Name -eq "SqlConnection") { $_ } }

Comment: [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683370.aspx) might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$Server = 'theServer'    
$database = 'theDatabase'
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server=$($Server);database=$($Database);trusted_connection=true;"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
$Command.CommandText = 'SELECT TOP 5 *  FROM yourTable ORDER BY 1 DESC'
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$Datatable.Load($Reader)
$Datatable | Export-Csv  report.csv -NoTypeInformation
$Connection.Close()
```

Comment: I am glad to help :)